# Calling nested div class in Javascript. Revised code not working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Need help.

I am creating a div inside body>div>div .

Reference: [Creating div in a nested class using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370879/creating-div-in-a-nested-class-using-javascript)

Here's a link to my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/41w8gjec/6/
Here's a link to the site https://bastioul.com/index.php/category/portfolio/ so you can see how the div is nested

Here's the wordpress classes.

```
class="archive category category-portfolio category-3 custom-background custom-header-image layout-two-column-default no-max-width"
>
class="hfeed"
>
class="site-content"
```

Here's my actual javascript code

```
function bastioul() {
  var dirty = document.querySelector('.category-portfolio>.hfeed>.site-content');
  var grime = dirty.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  grime.id = "portfolionav";
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', bastioul, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent('onload', bastioul);
}
```

No error messages in jsfiddle. I don't know enough about coding as far as php/javascript/jQuery is concerned to go through wordpress js files to see if something is negating my code. Not exactly sure of the root cause of my problem because it works in jsfiddle, and there is no console errors when i inspect page. I tried to research about the problem, but it is a pretty specific problem.

Not exactly sure what else to try.

Comment: when I inspect your fiddle, I can actually see this `<div class="hfeed site"><div class="site-content"><div id="portfolionav"></div></div></div>` looks like it is working, isn't it?

Comment: yes but if you go to my site it is not. it has something to do with wordpress theme im guessing, but i can't figure out why

Comment: I executed this `var dirty = document.querySelector('.category-portfolio>.hfeed>.site-content'); var grime = dirty.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  grime.id = "portfolionav";` inside chrome's inspector console on your website. It works

Comment: yes but if you view the website it does not work.

Comment: I guess the problem resides in window::load eventlistener. Did you try to bind it differently, like in jQuery `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Comment: i haven't learned jquery yet unfortunately. I wouldn't know how to rewrite the code into jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the issue by editing the functions.php for the wordpress theme I was using.

This is my php code.

```
wp_register_script( 'portfolionav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/portfolionav.js', array(), true );
 wp_enqueue_script('portfolionav');
 wp_footer();
```

**note**
I had a issue with this code because it automatically selects a library.

I used browsers inspect console error to show me what library was being called, and it was /themes/primer.

I uploaded my javascript to this library.

And now my script is running correctly on my Wordpress site.

I was not aware I had to add script by calling it in my php file when using Wordpress.